# Select fields in Laravel Eloquent with relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, subquery, relationship

How can I select fields in a laravel eloquent object what I mean

```
User::select('username', 'firstname', 'lastname')->with(['periods' => function($){
   $->select('jobtitle')->orderBy('start_date', 'desc')->limit(1);
}])->paginate(50);
```

in may case on this query I get periods null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use:

```
User::select('username', 'firstname', 'lastname')->with(['periods' => function($){
   $->select('jobtitle', 'user_id')->orderBy('start_date', 'desc')->limit(1);
}])->paginate(50);
```

instead. I've added `user_id`, because probably this is the column that joins periods with users. Eloquent cannot attach valid periods to users if you don't select column used for "matching" those records

Comment: thanks! that was I forgot to include the relation id

Answer (score 1):

You can solve following method in laravel 5.5 and newer version.

```
User::select('username', 'firstname', 'lastname')->with('periods:jobtitle')->get();
```

Comment: I tried but using with paginate does not brings any result

Comment: You can try whereHas method.

Comment: This won't work. You have to include the foreign key. I posted a new answer with the correct example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shorter syntax as suggested by FGDeveloper but you also have to include the foreign key as stated in the accepted answer:

```
User::select('username', 'firstname', 'lastname')->with('periods:user_id,jobtitle')->get();
```